# Bidirectional binding between BooleanProperty and ObjectProperty

Tags: java, javafx

I have BooleanProperty and ObjectProperty. What is the correct way to bind them depending on some condition, without adding change listeners to both of them?
Say, a have checkbox's selectedProperty, and position property ObjectProperty representing text alignment, and i have a condition "if boolean property is true then set position property to Pos.CENTER_LEFT and vice versa if position property is set to Pos.CENTER_LEFT, then set boolean property to true (otherwise false)". What is correct way to do this?
Here's piece of code:

```
        CheckBox alignmentSelector = new CheckBox("Set left alignment");
        ObjectProperty<Pos> positionProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        
        //Using two listeners approach
        alignmentSelector.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                positionProperty.set(newValue ? Pos.CENTER_LEFT : Pos.CENTER);
            }
        });
        
        positionProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Pos>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Pos> observable, Pos oldValue, Pos newValue) {
                alignmentSelector.selectedProperty().set(newValue.equals(Pos.CENTER_LEFT));
            }
        });
```

TLDR: I need to create custom bidirectional converter, that converts Pos to Boolean depending on condition and vice versa

I suppose there's best practice to achieve this without using two listeners, but I didn't find it neither in docs nor in examples.

Comment: If you check out the code in `javafx.beans.binding.Bindings.bindBidirectional` you will see that it ends up calling `addListener` on both properties. There are some interesting implementation details, you probably want to pay attention to them. So, I think that `addListener` is correct. There should be a standardized way to do that... I found [this](https://gist.github.com/amischler/72194b69e0b0938df522) that seems interesting.

Comment: There is a discussion about a similar problem in [the internet archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20180413203131/http://wittcarl.deneb.uberspace.de/wordpress/customized-bidirectional-bindings-in-javafx/).

Comment: Tomas Mikula's (now, I believe, unmaintained) [ReactFX library](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX/blob/master/reactfx/src/main/java/org/reactfx/value/Var.java) included a `Var` interface that extends the standard JavaFX `Property` API. It has a `mapBidirectional(Property<U>, Function<T,U>, Function<U,T>)` method you can emulate.